# Understanding the Storm Architecture

Tags: apache-storm

I have been trying to understand the storm architecture, but I am not sure if I got this right. I'll try to explain as exactly as possible what I believe to be the case. Please explain what - if - I got wrong and what is right.

### Preliminary thoughts: *workers*

http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html suggests that a Worker is a process as does http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Concepts.html with "worker processes. Each worker process is a physical JVM", however http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.1/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html states that a worker is a node with "Nimbus and worker machines". The website http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-multi-node-storm-cluster/ mentions "master node" and "worker nodes". So what: Is the worker a process or a physical node (or is a node a process)? Thus I think that there are two things: *Worker Nodes* and *Worker Processes*.

### What I believe to be true

#### Entities in play

- *Master Node* = Management Server
- *Worker Node* = *Slave Node*
- *Nimbus* JVM process, running on *Master Node*
- *ZooKeeper* JVM processes, running on *ZooKeeper Nodes*
- *Supervisor* JVM process, running on *Worker Nodes*
- *Worker Process* (JVM), running on *Worker Nodes*
- *Executor* thread, run by *Worker Process*
- *Task* (instances of *Bolts* and *Spouts*), executed by *Executor*

#### How things work

The *Nimbus* is a JVM process, running on the physical *Master Node*, that receives my program (*Storm topology*) takes the *Bolts and Spouts* and generates *tasks* from them. If a *Bolt* is supposed to be parallelized three times, the *Nimbus* generates three *tasks* for it. The *Nimbus* asks the *ZooKeeper* JVM processes about configurations of the cluster, e.g. where to run those *tasks* and the *ZooKeeper* JVM processes tells the *Nimbus*. In order to do this the *ZooKeeper* communicates with the *Supervisors* (what they are comes later). The *Nimbus* distributes the tasks then to the *Workers Nodes*, which are physical nodes. *Worker Nodes* are managed by *Supervisors*, which are JVM processes - exactly one *Supervisor* for one *Worker Node*. *Supervisors* manage (start, stop, etc.) the *Worker Processes*, which are JVM processes that run on the *Worker Nodes*. Each *Worker Node* can have multiple *Worker Processes* running. *Worker Processes* are JVM processes. They run one or multiple threads called *Executors*. Each *Executor Thread* runs one or multiple *Tasks*, meaning one or multiple instances of a *Bolt* or *Spout*, [but those have to be of the same *Bolt*](http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html).

If this is all true, it begs the questions:

- What is the point of having multiple *Worker Processes* run on one *Worker Node* - after all a process can use multiple processor cores, right?
- What is the point of having multiple *Tasks* run by one *Executor* thread if they have to be of the same *Bolt*/*Spout*? A thread is only run on one processor core, so the multiple *Bolt*/*Spout* have to run after each other and can not be parallelized. Running indefinitely in the Storm topology - what would be the point having two instances of the same *Bolt*/*Spout* in a *Exectuor* thread?

---

**Edit:** Good additional resource: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_storm/apache_storm_cluster_architecture.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a few clarification (basically you got it right).

- The term "node" and "process" are not always used consistently (unfortunately). But you got the "Entities in Play" correct.
- About parallelization: The number of tasks is determined by `.setNumTasks()` -- if not specified, it is the same as `parallelism_hint` (which sets the number of executors).
- About deployment: Nimbus gets cluster configuration from ZK, but ZK does **not** decides where to run a task -- Nimbus has a scheduler component that makes this decision (based on given topology, topology configuration, and cluster configuration).

To answer your question:

- A single worker process only executes task from a single topology. Thus, if you want to run multiple topologies you need multiple worker JVMs. The reason for this design is fault-tolerance, ie, isolation of topologies. If one topology fails (maybe due to bad user code), the crashing JVM does not affect other running topologies.
- Tasks allow for dynamic re-balancing and changing the parallelism at runtime. Without tasks, you would need to stop and redeploy a topology if you want to change the parallelism for a spout/bolt. Thus, the number of tasks defines your maximum parallelism for a spout/bolt. See https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.1/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html

Comment: And what does `parallelism_hint` denote? The number of *Executors*?

Comment: I was pretty sure that it is not possible to change the parallelism at runtime. Colleagues built a whole framework around storm because of this fact. Did this fact change since mid 2015? Even so my point still stands: How is having two tasks in an *Executor* thread help compared to having one? (The point of having multiple threads is to use multiple processor cores, right?)

Comment: Task feature is old -> 2012 v0.8.0: https://storm.apache.org/2012/08/02/storm080-released.html
If you have two tasks, you can keep separated data structures for each task, and thus move a whole task from machine to machine. If you have only a single task, you cannot split it (and thus, not move a share of the work to another machine). Of course, there is no advantage in the execution itself if a single executor runs multiple tasks. It's just about getting the flexibility to "over partition" your program using more tasks than executors, to allow for adding executors at runtime later on.

Comment: If I have only identical tasks in an Executor, I could just copy the task to an Executor on a different machine. I don't need a duplicate. If I split the task into two tasks and they are different, in order to have some of the work done by an Executor on a different node, then the assumption that the tasks are identical is violated...

Comment: "Identical" mean they execute the same code -- but each task gets a different sub-stream to apply the code on (think "fieldsGrouping"). Ie, you can move a task to another machine and redirect the corresponding sub-stream to the new machine, too. (But splitting a task and a substream into two tasks and two sub-streams would be very hard to get done)

Comment: Yes. Using rebalane you can set new parallelism_hint values.